# openvpn route only ssh traffic over vpn connection

Tags: openvpn

I have a OpenVPN server and we would like all traffic to go out the end users internet but if they are Developer and they are using SSH to the AWS servers I would like that traffic to go out the VPN connection and appear as though they are internal to the company.

Comment: Could you post your configuration?

Comment: Yo, I heard you liked encrypted connections so I put an encrypted connections in your encrypted connection so can you have an encryption when you encrypt your connection.

Comment: BTW your answer is more or less at the following link if you really think you need this for some reason.  http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html